# SQL to calculate viewing time for each viewing from video viewing log

Tags: sql, presto

There is a table in which data of the video viewing log as follows is stored.

```
|user_id| status |     time         |
-------------------------------------
|user_a |start   |2019-06-18 00:00:00|
|user_a |progress|2019-06-18 00:00:05|
|user_a |progress|2019-06-18 00:00:10|
|user_a |complete|2019-06-18 00:00:15|
|user_a |start   |2019-06-18 00:10:00|
|user_a |complete|2019-06-18 00:10:05|
|user_b |start   |2019-06-18 00:20:00|
|user_b |progress|2019-06-18 00:20:05|
|user_b |progress|2019-06-18 00:20:10|
```

From the above table, I would like to calculate how many seconds each video has been viewed for each user viewing.

The image is below.

```
|user_id|views_num|time(second) |
|user_a |1        |15           |
|user_a |2        |5            |
|user_b |1        |10           |
```

Logs are recorded every 5 seconds.

Is there a way to aggregate with sql?

I am using presto.

Comment: How do you have two rows for `user_a`, when there's nothing in the table that distinguishes between the video logs? Also the number of views doesn't correlate for `user_a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected output can be achieved from below.

> Using **subquery** as a column expression on the same table

```
SELECT t.user AS "user_id"
    ,row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY t.user ORDER BY TIME
        ) AS "views_num"
    ,EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (COALESCE(t.complete, t.progress) - t.TIME)) AS "time(second)"
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,(
            SELECT min(TIME)
            FROM log l2
            WHERE l1.user = l2.user
                AND l2.STATUS = 'complete'
                AND l1.TIME < l2.TIME
            ) complete
        ,(
            SELECT max(TIME)
            FROM log l3
            WHERE l1.user = l3.user
                AND l3.STATUS = 'progress'
                AND l1.TIME < l3.TIME
            ) progress
    FROM log l1
    WHERE l1.STATUS = 'start'
    ) t
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jsmVws7NZzaoVZ3MvgY6p2/1)

**Output**

```
| user_id | views_num | time(second) |
| ------- | --------- | ------------ |
| user_a  | 1         | 15           |
| user_a  | 2         | 5            |
| user_b  | 1         | 10           |
```

In PrestoDB use date_diff instead of `EXTRACT(EPOCH())` which is used in postgre.
The demo is using postgre DB. You can change the line as below and it should work.

```
date_diff('second', COALESCE(t.complete, t.progress),t.TIME) AS "time(second)"
```

[prestosql date_diff](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)

Comment: I ran in presto but got an error. An error "Invalid EXTRACT failed: EPOCH" will occur. Presto may not support that syntax.

Comment: date_diff('second', COALESCE(t.complete, t.progress),t.TIME)

Comment: Thanks!! I did well.